# Excel VBA Reference load issue

Tags: vba, excel

I've been attempting to add a reference to a specific DLL, and after several attempts I've found a bit of code that actually works. However when I attempt it with the DLL that is supposed to work in Excel, it gives me an error and refuses to load.

I've tested this code with a few DLLs that came with Excel/Windows, and I've had no issues.. Was wondering if perhaps there is some 'install' process I need to go through with new DLLs or something of that sort.

Runtime-error '48'

Error in loading DLL

Code:

```
Sub AddReference()
Dim VBAEditor As VBIDE.VBE
Dim vbProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim chkRef As Reference
Dim BoolExists As Boolean

Set VBAEditor = Application.VBE
Set vbProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

'~~> Check if "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" is already added
For Each chkRef In vbProj.References
    If chkRef.Name = "VBScript_RegExp_55" Then
        BoolExists = True
        GoTo CleanUp
    End If
Next

vbProj.References.AddFromFile "C:\WINDOWS\system32\HIDDEN.dll"

CleanUp:
If BoolExists = True Then
    MsgBox "Reference already exists"
Else
    MsgBox "Reference Added Successfully"
End If

Set vbProj = Nothing
Set VBAEditor = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Is that a 32 or 64 bit dll you are loading? The bits of Office and the dll might be conflicting.

Comment: That is a good point actually, I just found that Office is 32 bit.

Comment: It was the version of Office causing the issue, thank you.

Comment: No problem. I just added an answer. If you need more help, let me know.

Comment: Most certainly, and I was hoping you would. ^^ Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this kind of problems are related to conflicting bit versions of Office and the DLL you are loading.

Try to load the correct version of the DLL.